# codeigniter 4 mysqli_sql_exception #1064 in view

Tags: codeigniter, mysql-error-1064, codeigniter-4

It's very strange for me. Because in codeigniter 4 one of my function is working in controller but not working in view. I am getting my data's from database in controller, but when I am trying to get same data from view it showing `mysqli_sql_exception #1064`.

Example codes:

**In Controller `(MyData.php)`**

```
function get_data($status){
    return $this->Data->get_data($status);
}

function view_data(){
    return view('user/view-data',['data'=>$this])
}
```

**In Model `(MyData.php)`**

```
function get_data($status="approved"){
    return $this->select()->where('status',$status)->get()->getResultArray();
}
```

**In View `(MyData.php)`**

```
$datas = $data->get_data('approved');
```

**Error**

```
mysqli_sql_exception #1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*, *, *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your `view_data` function should be

```
function view_data(){
    return view('user/view-data',['data'=>$this->get_data('approved')])
}
```

Then in view just loop through the `$data` array

Views are places that you MUST NOT need to execute sql queries. You need to pass only data (objects, arrays, string, int, etc.) to views.

Comment: Hi brother thank you for your answer. You can see that I am passing my controller object (that contain my model data also) to my view in data array and I am not exacting any sql queries in my view.  My question is why I am getting mysqli_sql_exception #1064.  Other functions are working fine except this function.

Comment: Running queries in view is against the idea MVC. If you really want to run query in views you need to initiate database connection in each view. Up to you but I don't recommend it.

Comment: I am not running any query in view and controller also, I am getting my data from my model.

Comment: No, your model trying to run query while database is not loaded in view scope. That's why you should pass only the actual data to view not the whole codeigniter object.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did the same thing in another function, that is working. In that case I had pass the controller object in view and accessed the whole data. But in this function I am failed to get my data. Whatever until next solution I will pass function data in view Instead of controller object.